# Python pandas Dataframe : Delete all rows until the first occurrence of a certain value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, pandas-groupby

I have a pandas 'Dataframe' which looks looks like, also please let me know if you need `pd.Dataframe` to the below table.

```
iD      a   b   c
c1      2   3   4
c1      2   3   4
c1      2   3   4
c1      2   E   4
c1      2   3   4
c2      3   4   5
c2      3   4   5
c2      3   E   5
c2      3   4   5
```

now in this dataframe there are two IDs c1 and c2. I want to delete all the rows above whenever 'E' appears in column 'b'.

my final dataframe should look like

```
iD      a   b   c
c1      2   E   4
c1      2   3   4
c2      3   E   5
c2      3   4   5
```

Just trying to keep the question short for people to answer. Please let me know if i have to add some extra datapoints in dataframe

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) and [`cumsum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.cumsum.html) on a mask of boolean values comparing the column "b" to the letter "E":

```
df[df.b.eq('E').groupby(df.iD).cumsum()]

   iD  a  b  c
3  c1  2  E  4
4  c1  2  3  4
7  c2  3  E  5
8  c2  3  4  5
```

---

```
df[df.b.eq('E').groupby(df.iD).cumsum()].reset_index(drop=True)

   iD  a  b  c
0  c1  2  E  4
1  c1  2  3  4
2  c2  3  E  5
3  c2  3  4  5
```

Comment: Nice use of `cumsum` here, great solution!

Comment: @PuneetSinha in general asking for votes is discouraged, but I see you have genuinely tried improving the question so I've upvoted it.

Comment: thanks Man....  I wounot have asked it ... but .. i am not able to ask any new questions

Answer (score 1):

You could [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) `iD` and and use `boolean indexing` with [`idxmax`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.idxmax.html) to keep from where the first `B` is found onwards:

```
df.groupby('iD').apply(lambda x: x.loc[(x.b == 'E').idxmax():,:])
                .reset_index(drop=True)

   iD  a  b  c
0  c1  2  E  4
1  c1  2  3  4
2  c2  3  E  5
3  c2  3  4  5
```